# Как получить новый массив, который обьединен по условию в цикле: одинаковый price и user_id,при этом сложить все count?

Tags: php

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [id_user] => 20
            [count] => 2
            [price] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [id_user] => 20
            [count] => 5
            [price] => 1000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [id_user] => 21
            [count] => 3
            [price] => 1000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [id_user] => 20
            [count] => 3
            [price] => 2000
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [id_user] => 22
            [count] => 3
            [price] => 3500
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [id_user] => 21
            [count] => 10
            [price] => 1000
        )

)
======== результат,который хочется получить ==============
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [id_user] => 20
            [count] => 17
            [price] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [id_user] => 21
            [count] => 13
            [price] => 1000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [id_user] => 20
            [count] => 4
            [price] => 2000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [id_user] => 22
            [count] => 3
            [price] => 3500
        )

)    

 $arr = [
        ['id' => 1, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 2, 'price' => 1000],
        ['id' => 2, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 5, 'price' => 1000],
        ['id' => 3, 'id_user' => 21, 'count' => 3, 'price' => 1000],
        ['id' => 4, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 3, 'price' => 2000],
        ['id' => 5, 'id_user' => 22, 'count' => 3, 'price' => 3500],
        ['id' => 6, 'id_user' => 21, 'count' => 10, 'price' => 1000],
    ];

    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        foreach ($arr as $item2) {

            if ($item['price'] == $item2['price'] && $item['user_id'] == $item2['user_id'])
                $merge_arr[]['count'] += $item2['count'];
                // .............
        }
    }
    // результат который хочется получить
    $merge_arr = [
        ['id' => 1, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 17, 'price' => 1000],
        ['id' => 4, 'id_user' => 21, 'count' => 13, 'price' => 1000],
        ['id' => 2, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 4, 'price' => 2000],
        ['id' => 5, 'id_user' => 22, 'count' => 3, 'price' => 3500],
    ];
    print_r($arr);
    print_r($merge_arr);`введите сюда код`
```

Comment: играйте с ключом массива. id пользователя уникален. Ключ массива - тоже. Перед добавлением в массив новой строки проверяете, существует ли ключ. Если нет, то заносите новую запись. Если да, то просто прибавляете стоимость

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так, только что делать с 'id' по вопросу не понял

```
 $arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 2, 'price' => 1000],
    ['id' => 2, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 5, 'price' => 1000],
    ['id' => 3, 'id_user' => 21, 'count' => 3, 'price' => 1000],
    ['id' => 4, 'id_user' => 20, 'count' => 3, 'price' => 2000],
    ['id' => 5, 'id_user' => 22, 'count' => 3, 'price' => 3500],
    ['id' => 6, 'id_user' => 21, 'count' => 10, 'price' => 1000],
];

foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    $newID=$v['id_user'].' '.$v['price'];
    $users[$newID]=['id_user' => $v['id_user'], 'price' => $v['price']];
    $users[$newID]['count']+=$v['count'];
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($users);
```